# children UIViews to inherit parent transparency level

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicolor

For whatever reason, sometimes when I set the transparency level of a UIView, the transparency level cascades to all of its children subviews. But sometimes it does not. I am not sure why. I don't think I ever do anything special. So what are the conditions for making sure that a child view inherits the transparency level of its parent? By transparency level, I mean `alpha`

**Particular Case**

I have successfully placed a UISearchBar as the subview of a `self.navigationItem.titleView`. But the UISearchBar's TextField and Images (magnifying glass and delete X mark) are not taking on the transparency of the parent view.

Answer (score 0):

A view's `alpha` is applied to the whole view (including its subviews - though the subviews' `alpha` values aren't actually changed). If you set a view's alpha to 0, the whole view disappears, including all subviews.

If you set a subview alpha to 0.5 and then set the view alpha to 0.5, the subview alpha is effectively 0.25.

It would help if you gave a more specific example where you say this doesn't happen. What do you actually see?